# jquery dynamically change class

Tags: jquery

When i do console log following is the html structure, that is printed:

```
<div class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" data-id="21">
          <div class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
             <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>
             <h6>First Person</h6>
          </div>
          <p class="style-content"></p>
          <p class="style-content">Estimated Missing: 10</p>
          <p class="style-content">
            <span class="sub_task">6</span> 
            People Found
          </p>
        </div>
```

I want to add additional class `delta` to `<span class="sub_task">6</span>` if a given variable `alpha = "12"`

As of now my js file looks like this:

```
console.log(elem)
elem = $(this).children()[3];
if (alpha=="12"){
elem.addClass("delta");
}
```

but this gives an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLParagraphElement> has no method 'addClass'
```

I have two questions:

a better selector to get the element.

how can i add the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$` or `jQuery` **since `addClass` is a function of jQuery**:

```
$(elem).addClass("delta");
```

Or

```
jQuery(elem).addClass("delta");
```

Also change:

```
elem = $(this).children()[3];
```

To:

```
elem = $(this).children().eq(2).find('span'); // note index starts at 0 in eq
```

Or you can add class directly like this (assuming you have same html structure)

```
if (alpha == "12") {
   $('.style-content').find('span').addClass("delta");
}
```

Comment: While it's true that addClass is a jQuery function, the problem does not lie with the selector but rather with the way OP uses .children and selects an element.

Comment: Note that when elem is properly defined with .children, elem.addClass() also works fine.

Comment: @Joey: Yes that's true which would be `elem = $(this).children().eq(2).find('p');` as I said in my answer, it will work in either way then

Comment: @Blaster as you can see there are three *p*s and the last one only has a span, also i want to add the class to span, not the p, as mentioned in my question, currently the class is being added to p.

Comment: @Blaster but modifying it slightly served my purpose, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both answers in one snippet:

```
$(this).children().eq(3).addClass('delta');
```

Comment: He wants to add class conditionally

Comment: @Blaster - I'm just fixing the one line.  This goes inside of his condition.